# Shapefile created from Whitebox GAT has no *. prj file?

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, whitebox-gat

I am new to Whitebox GAT.

I found out that the shapefile I created in it does not have projection file.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: No, you are doing OK. WhiteBox-GAT works in XY space and does not do much about CRS. (It has `Coordinate System Transformation` tool, though). Each Map belongs to its own xy-coords, which enables us to work on multiple CRS at the same time.

Comment: If you need prj file, go to [EPSG.io](http://epsg.io/) to find your CRS and download `ESRI WKT` text file.